# bufferedreader won't move to the next line

Tags: java, bufferedreader, stringtokenizer

Good evening,

I need to read some lines from a file, the file is csv and the file is structured like so:

```
4,
Mo Farah,30,
Jessica Ennis,27,
```

i need to read those values and put them into variables, that's how i tried to do this:

```
  while(nextline != null){
           StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(nextline,",");
           int size = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
           System.out.println(size);

           nextline = reader.readLine();

           StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(nextline, ","); //why???


           String name = st2.nextToken();
           System.out.println(name);
           int age = Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());

           System.out.println(age);
```

the first int (4) is read just fine, however if i want to move to the next line it throws a noSuchElementException, so i had to write the line next to "//why???" in order to move to the next line, do i really have to instantiate a new tokenizer each time i want to move to the next line? or is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, you need to make a new tokenizer for each line (or reset the existing one too use the new line) because the tokenizer contains a state that is linked to the line being processed.

Comment: wow, that seems like such a waste, can i ask you to show me how to reset the token? and add this as an answer? thanks

Comment: Don't use a StringTokenizer -- use `String#split` instead, as @Mark recommends (although his code has some problems with it).

Comment: Actually creating objects i Java is REALLY fast. It may look like a waste if you're coming from C++ but in reality it is not wastefull at all. The language is designed to be used like this. I just looked at the java doc, there is no reset function, just make a new tokenizer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Lets have a look at what goes on

```
nextline = reader.readLine(); // I'm assuming you have this here
while(nextline != null){
```

The following will parse the line `"4,"` and split it into tokens separated by `,` it will contain 1 token: `"4"`:

```
       StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(nextline,",");
```

The following will succeed but you really should check that `st.hasMoreTokens()` returns true before doing this. It will consume the token `"4"` from the `st` which now contains no more tokens:

```
       int size = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
       System.out.println(size);

       // We read the next line into "nextline", this is okay but not pretty.
       // Also you need to check that nextline is not `null` here.
       nextline = reader.readLine();

       StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(nextline, ","); //why???
```

### Why?

Because `st` was made to parse the line `"4,"`. Assigning `nextline` after the line has been parsed does not update the internal state of `st` (it's impossible to achieve). It simply doesn't work that way. So if you call `st.nextToken()` here, you will get `NoSuchElementException` as you said. Because you already read the `"4"` from `st` and there are no tokens left.

The following is the right thing to do if you want to use `StringTokenizer`, it will cause the line `"Mo Farah,30,"` to be parsed to tokens: `"Mo Farah"` and `"30"`:

```
       st = new StringTokenizer(nextline, ","); // Just parse the new line.
       // You can reuse the old st variable as it is now depleted.
```

The following will now return the first token from the next line which is `"Mo Farah"`. Although again, you really should check `st.hasMoreTokens()` first and give a reasonable error message:

```
       String name = st.nextToken(); // Change from st2 to st
       System.out.println(name);
       int age = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); // Ditto

       System.out.println(age);
```

So the short answer is, yes, if you want to use `StringTokenizer` you have to make a new `StringTokenizer` for every line. If you don't care above line endings you can just read all lines and concatenate them before passing all of it to the `StringTokenizer`.

But the easiest thing to do is just to use String tokens[] = newline.split(","); as Mark did in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

If i suppose the pattern in csv is always the same...:

```
  while(nextline != null){ 

      String[] lecture = reader.readLine().split(",");

       if(lecture.lenght()>0){
                  System.out.println("Name: " + lecture[0]);
               int age = Integer.parseInt(lecture[1]);//you need to int?

                  System.out.println(lecture[1]);
        }
              else
                  System.out.println("Name: " + lecture[0]);
    }
```

hope this helps...